# Suspension for almost 6 months for plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, account-suspension

I just stumbled upon a user profile who has:

> This account is temporarily suspended for plagiarism. The suspension
>   period ends on Mar 13 '15 at 5:31.

[image]

I am not sure since when he/she been suspended, but what could warrant such a long suspension? Did he present Dijkstra's algorithm in his/her name or his/her post was flagged by Jon Skeet?

I mean, suspension for almost 6 months for plagiarism? I have seen users being suspended for a week for offences like these; has the current policy been changed?

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't a single, isolated incident but a repeated pattern.

Comment: Mods & the CM's won't discussion the circumstances around this specific instance, so I doubt you will get the answer you are looking for except that it was either repeated or egregious.

Comment: It doesn't matter what was plagiarized or who flagged it. We look at severity and patterns of behavior to determine the length of suspension periods.

Comment: I don't know what he/she did, but I believe the judgement of the Moderators is/was correct. I've seen cases where answers have been *completely* copied. This isn't fair on the people who put in a lot of effort in their answers.

Comment: The only lesson to be learnt is "Do not plagiarize", rest of the information doesn't matter as Bill has already mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments, What is so bad about this question that it has been downvoted so much ? I didn't specify the user or said it was wrong. Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Moderators will not discuss individual cases. The user's behaviour has been addressed, that's it, and we won't be told the details however much we might be intrigued.

Temporary suspensions are not handed out lightly, and initial suspensions normally start with a *short* period. A longer period like 6 months is usually only handed out when preceding shorter suspensions did not lead to better behaviour. See [*A Day in the Penalty Box*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-Penalty-Box/).

In other words, in all probability there was a systemic pattern of plagiarism and the user repeated the behaviour after earlier, shorter suspensions. This suspension was not handed out for a single isolated incident.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No one gets a very long suspension for the first offense; if they ignore the first suspension and go back to plagiarizing, the suspensions get longer fairly quickly. These tend to be extremely labor-intensive for both moderators and users to handle, so folks who ignore [the guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) are seriously disruptive.